Why does my C++ function run 10x faster than the C# P/Invoke call?
I have a C++ function that uses AVX2 intrinsics to brighten an image. When I measure the performance directly in C++, it takes around 500 microseconds to process an image with a resolution of 3840 x 240. However, when I call the same function from C# using P/Invoke, it takes about 4 milliseconds, which is much slower.
For an 3840 x 2160 image native C++ takes about 1.5ms while P/Invoke takes about 4.5 ms.
For an 10000 x 4000 image native C++ takes about 3 ms while P/Invoke takes about 8 ms.
Here is my setup:
C++: A native function that processes the image data using AVX2.
C#: Uses P/Invoke to call this function, passing the image data directly by reference.
C# main program:
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    int width = 3840;
    int height = 240;
    byte[] image = new byte[width * height];
    Random random = new Random();
    
    // Fill the image array with random brightness values between 0 and 255
    for (int i = 0; i < image.Length; i++)
    {
        image[i] = (byte)random.Next(0, 256);
    }

    byte brightness = 30;
    
    // Measure C# processing time
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    ProcessorCSharp.BrightenImage(image, brightness);
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("C# Time: {0} microseconds", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds * 1000);
}

C# Wrapper Class:
public class ProcessorCSharp
{
    [DllImport("ImageProcessingLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void brightenImageSIMD(IntPtr image, int size, byte brightness);

    public static unsafe void BrightenImage(byte[] image, byte brightness)
    {
        int size = image.Length;

        fixed (byte* p = image)
        {
            brightenImageSIMD((IntPtr)p, size, brightness);
        }
    }
}

C++ Function:
#include <immintrin.h>  // AVX2 intrinsics
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    // For std::min

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) // in my main c++ code this line doesn't exist
void brightenImageSIMD(uint8_t* image, size_t size, uint8_t brightness) {
    size_t i = 0;
    __m256i brightnessVector = _mm256_set1_epi8(brightness);
    __m256i maxVector = _mm256_set1_epi8(255);

    for (; i + 31 < size; i += 32) {
        __m256i pixels = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*) &image[i]);
        __m256i brightened = _mm256_adds_epu8(pixels, brightnessVector);
        __m256i clamped = _mm256_min_epu8(brightened, maxVector);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*) &image[i], clamped);
    }

    for (; i < size; ++i) {
        image[i] = std::min(image[i] + brightness, 255);
    }
}

// Helper function to measure execution time
template <typename Func, typename... Args>
long long measureExecutionTime(Func func, Args&&... args) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count();
}

int main() {
    const int width = 3840;
    const int height = 2160;
    const uint8_t brightnessIncrease = 30;

    std::vector<uint8_t> image(width * height);

    // Set up random number generation
    std::random_device rd;  // Seed for the random number engine
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // Standard mersenne_twister_engine
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 255); // Range from 0 to 255 for 8-bit brightness levels

    // Fill the image with random values
    for (auto& pixel : image) {
        pixel = static_cast<uint8_t>(dis(gen));
    }

    // Measure performance of SIMD method
    auto imageCopy3 = image; // Make another copy for fair comparison
    long long timeSIMD = measureExecutionTime(brightenImageSIMD, imageCopy3, brightnessIncrease);

    std::cout << "SIMD (AVX2) method time: " << timeSIMD << " microseconds" << std::endl;
    

    return 0;
}

Problem:
The main reason for me trying C++ wrapped functions in C# is I need better performance than I am achieving in C# for realtime image processing applications.
For example in C++ alone, brightenImageSIMD takes around 500 microseconds. But when I call it from C#, it consistently takes about 4 milliseconds. I've tried using unsafe code with a fixed pointer to prevent array copying, but the performance difference remains.
Questions:
Why is there such a large performance gap between the native C++ execution and the C# P/Invoke call?
What can I do to bring the C#-called version closer to the performance of the native C++?
How does libraries like OpenCvSharp achieve excellent performance with P/Invoke? OpenCvSharp calls native OpenCV functions via P/Invoke and still maintains very high performance, so I'm curious if there are techniques from that library that could apply here that I am missing.
NOTE: I AM USING .NET FRAMEWORK 4.8
NOTE: I RAN BOTH OF THEM 100 TIMES AND TOOK THE AVERAGE OF THEIR PROCESSING TIME. THEY ARE VERY SIMILAR TO EACH OTHER NOW. HOWEVER IN MY USE CASE I CANT RUN A FUNCTION 100 TIMES FOR IT TO RUN FASTER.

I'd recommend trying out BenchmarkDotnet to get stable and reliable numbers.

if you're only calling it once, you could be measuring a lot of one-time JIT work, including resolving and loading the external dll, resolving the method in the exported method table, building the interop wrapper etc; maybe call it once first and ignore that, then measure it a bunch of times. Even better: use a tool like BenchmarkDotNet which will take care of such things for you. As a minor thing; you might find it easier to just use void* or byte* instead of IntPtr on the extern method

This isn't related to your question directly, but is there any reason you're not using C#'s SIMD capabilities? That will keep everything nicely in managed code

I do not see anything in the C++ code preventing the last loop in brightenImageSIMD to be optimized away after inlining, since you never access image afterwards. In fact the whole function call has no relevant side effect, so it may be optimized away completely if you are (un)lucky.

A difference is the allocation position between the 2 arrays. The C# array is likely to be located on the LOH, while the std::vector is on the stack. It is well known that the cost is different. You may try the same way to create the image data.

this can all probably be done very efficiently in pure C#; relevant link: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.avx2 (or if not that: it'll be close by); to get from byte[] to Vector256<yoursizehere> etc:  MemoryMarshal.Cast - something like: (here using int as the element i.e. Vector256<int>) https://gist.github.com/mgravell/b9dfa49be2aa8d1999e7df90fa38c259

Unrelated: Don't use high_resolution_clock. Use steady_clock instead. Even the author of high_resolution_clock says so.

My fairly naive port comes in at 30us on my machine. Granted that's completely different hardware to you, and I haven't compared it to the C++ version on my machine, but that's the sort of order of magnitude I'd expect

random question: what is the point of _mm256_min_epu8 here with an upper bound of 255? we already know the numbers aren't going to be larger than 255, since they're bytes...

However I don't think you need the _mm256_min_epu8 there, as the _mm256_adds_epu8 already saturates at 255, which brings it down to 25us.

@canton7 I love that this is clearly eating  away at us in similar ways...

@canton7 I can't use SIMD in .Net framework 4.8 unfortunately.

You say you ran each of them 100 times. That's probably excessive: did you try running them twice and taking the second time? As mentioned, the C# runtime has to do a lot of things on the first run (JIT compilation, building the interop wrapper, loading the DLL, etc), which will be skewing your measurements significantly

.Net framework do not use tiered compilation, so the first time a method is called it gets compiled, this will take some time, but only happens first time. If this is a problem you should probably reconsider using .Net, or use AOT compilation available in newer .Net versions.

@canton7 Your port is awesome however my project is using .net framework which cant use both span and SIMD.

@canton7 When I run them 2 times at 3840x2160 for C++ it is 1ms and C# it is 1.7ms.

@MustafaVisys okay well, how many times are you running it in the real application ? like once a second, once a minute ? or once an hour ? i don't think this is a concern when you add 3 milliseconds to the entire runtime of the application which will take a few seconds to load anyway, if the entire application should take a few milliseconds (like CLI tools) then C# is probably not the right tool anyway, or any language with a VM or a garbage collector for that matter, but if this function runs like a few times a second then all the JIT overhead will happen in the first second anyway.

@canton7 for your interest, perhaps: on modern .NET (so won't help OP) there are faster (less safe) ways of creating spans; I'm thinking ref byte origin = ref image[0]; at the start, and new Span<byte>(Unsafe.AddByteOffset(ref origin, i), 32) in the loop; untested, however

@MustafaVisys if perf is important to you, moving to .NET 8 (or soon: .NET 9) really should be a priority; I realise it isn't trivial, and I know lots of teams still struggling to make that leap, but: it is hugely beneficial - and you'll have lots of new tools to play with ;p

@Ahmed AEK
It is a realtime application that should process 3000 frames per second. This C++ function will be called 3000 times a sec.

@MustafaVisys so if the first 10 calls to the function are slower, will that really matter when it is being called 3000 times a second ?

@Ahmed AEK It might not actually. I was torn between moving to .net 8 or using C++. When I saw OpenCVSharp performing superb I considered C++. Still dont know how OpenCvSharp manages to do that.

@MarcGravell Sure: I'd hesitate to recommend that on SO if a safe alternative exists however!

@Marc Gravell Thanks for the suggestion. I was really hoping for an alternative way but maybe .net 8 is the way to go unless I somehow learn OpenCvSharps trick!

@MustafaVisys it is doing pretty much the same thing https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/blob/main/src/OpenCvSharp/Internal/PInvoke/NativeMethods/core/NativeMethods_core.cs i think the main difference is that they pre-load the dll, while in your case the dll is being loaded on the first call which make the problem look worse than it actually is, but it is the same time overall. for what it is worth i don't think you need to do anything about this, but keep tracking the achievable FPS from both C++ and C# and work based on it, instead of worrying about the first few calls

@MustafaVisys the migration from dotnet framework to dotnet 8 should ultimately be based on the target platforms, remember that you do lose support for some platforms in the process. it is recommended you use dotnet8 if it satisfies your platform requirements, but if it doesn't then you are pretty much stuck on dotnet framework

@Ahmed AEK I learn how to pre-load DLL's and give it a try I guess!

@MustafaVisys opencvsharp is doing a lot of stuff to ensure proper pathing, but the simplest form is that you add a dummy function to the dll that does nothing and call it at the start of the application, this will essentially load the dll.

@ Ahmed AEK It did make a difference! I Preloaded the DLL like OpenCvSharp and it is faster now. Now I will try my real methods if it helps. THANK YOU for the suggestion.

For actual benchmarking you should use BenchmarkDotNet, which does things like warmup runs.

If you want to understand performance, in additional to benchmarking, you should also consider running the profiler.  Then you can see exactly where the time is being spent.

The delay was indeed caused by the initial loading of the DLL when the function was first called. In .NET, using P/Invoke to call unmanaged functions can have an overhead the first time a function is invoked, as it involves loading the external DLL into memory. This can add a noticeable delay, especially in performance-sensitive applications where even slight delays matter.
To avoid this first-call delay, I resolved the issue by preloading the DLL at the start of my application, well before the function was needed.
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class DllLoader
{
    [DllImport("ImageProcessingLib.dll", CallingConvention = 
CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void DummyFunction();

    public static void Load()
    {
        // Calling a dummy function just to load the DLL
        DummyFunction();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Preload the DLL to avoid loading delay on the first function call
    DllLoader.Load();

    // Now we can call other functions without the initial load overhead
}

This is one of the reasons OpenCvSharp runs fast in C#!

We did say in the comments that there would be a delay the first time that you ran your function, as the runtime has to load the DLL and generate some code. That's where the suggestion to run it twice and take the second time came from :)

This is a technique I applied a number if times in the past: do a start screen with a loading bar that would instantiate 1 type of each dll, to just dispose it. This increased the app start time (which was once a day) but made it faster overall.

There are lots of overheads in calling out to unmanaged code, at least for the first call which is what you're measuring; but: we don't need to; unless I've got something wrong, this should work fine:
(note I removed the clamped usage, since we're clamping to the value already enforced by the saturation)
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86;

int width = 3840;
int height = 240;
byte[] image = new byte[width * height];
Random.Shared.NextBytes(image);

const byte brightness = 30;
ProcessorCSharp.BrightenImage(image, brightness);

public class ProcessorCSharp
{
    public static void BrightenImage(Span<byte> image, byte brightness)
    {
        if (Avx2.IsSupported)
        {
            var chunks = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, Vector256<byte>>(image);
            var brightnessVector = Vector256.Create<byte>(brightness);
            for (int i = 0; i < chunks.Length; i++)
            {
                chunks[i] = Avx2.AddSaturate(chunks[i], brightnessVector);
            }
            // cut off what we've dealt with
            image = image.Slice(32 * chunks.Length);
        }
        // deal with any leftover bytes (or everything if AVX2 isn't available)
        for (int i = 0; i < image.Length; i++)
        {
            image[i] = (byte)Math.Min(image[i] + brightness, 255);
        }
    }
}


Interestingly in my benchmarking, doing a MemoryMarshal.Cast of the whole array was slightly slower than just doing a naive Vector256.Create of each chunk (and a CopyTo to store it back)

@canton7 interesting; is that the byte[],int overload? great catch! again showing the value of things like BDN (or whatever tool you've used) when discussing perf

@canton7 I'd also want to test foreach (ref Vector256<byte> chunk in chunks) with chunk = Avx2.AddSaturate(chunk, brightnessVector); - although I'd expect that to JIT very similarly to the int i approach

It was the span overload, although benchmarking (BDN) our two approaches side-by-side, yours is now slightly quicker, so I'm not sure... They're pretty close, anyway

The foreach ref approach does speed it up a small amount. The difference is much more pronounced on larger images

Why is there such a large performance gap between the native C++ execution and the C# P/Invoke call?
Generally for SIMD in general C++ is performing better than C#, that would naturally explain the time delta here. In fact, the compiler doesn't behave the same when treating the same snippet of code for both language :
C# JIT ASM AVX:
xor         edx,edx                          ; initialise edx (loop counter i) to zero

; LOOP_START
mov         ecx,dword ptr [rsi+8]            ; load vx.Length into ecx
cmp         edx,ecx                          ; if i >= vx.Length
jae         000007FE95B958E7                 ; throw IndexOutOfRangeException
lea         r8d,[rdx+3]                      ; load i+3 into r8d
cmp         r8d,ecx                          ; if i+3 >= vx.Length
jae         000007FE95B958E7                 ; throw IndexOutOfRangeException
movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rsi+rdx*4+10h] ; load vx[i..i+3] into xmm0

mov         ecx,dword ptr [rdi+8]            ; load vy.Length into ecx
cmp         edx,ecx                          ; if i >= vy.Length
jae         000007FE95B958E7                 ; throw IndexOutOfRangeException
cmp         r8d,ecx                          ; if i+3 >= vy.Length
jae         000007FE95B958E7                 ; throw IndexOutOfRangeException
movups      xmm1,xmmword ptr [rdi+rdx*4+10h] ; load vy[i..i+3] into xmm1

paddd       xmm0,xmm1                        ; perform SIMD addition of xmm0 and xmm1
mov         ecx,dword ptr [rax+8]            ; load result.Length into ecx
cmp         edx,ecx                          ; if i >= result.Length
jae         000007FE95B958EC                 ; throw ArgumentException
cmp         r8d,ecx                          ; if i+3 >= result.Length
jae         000007FE95B958F1                 ; throw ArgumentException

movups      xmmword ptr [rax+rdx*4+10h],xmm0 ; more result out of xmm0 into the result array

add         edx,4                            ; increment loop counter, i, by 4
cmp         edx,3E8h                         ; if i < 1000 (0x3E8)
jl          000007FE95B9589A                 ; go back to LOOP_START

C++ MSVC2015 AVX2:
; array initialisation and loop setup omitted...

; SIMD_LOOP_START
vmovdqu     ymm1,ymmword ptr [rax-20h]           ; load 8 ints (256 bits) from x into 256-bit register ymm1
vpaddd      ymm1,ymm1,ymmword ptr [rcx+rax-20h]  ; add 8 ints from y to those in ymm1 and store result back in ymm1
vmovdqu     ymmword ptr [r8+rax-20h],ymm1        ; move result out of ymm1 into the result array
vmovdqu     ymm2,ymmword ptr [rax]               ; load the next 8 ints from x into ymm2
vpaddd      ymm1,ymm2,ymmword ptr [rcx+rax]      ; add the next 8 ints from y to those in ymm2 and store the result in ymm1
vmovdqu     ymmword ptr [r8+rax],ymm1            ; move the result out of ymm1 into the result array
lea         rax,[rax+40h]                        ; increment the array indexer by 16 ints (64 bytes)
sub         r9,1                                 ; decrement the loop counter
jne         main+120h                            ; if loop counter != 0 go back to SIMD_LOOP_START

; SIMPLE_LOOP_START
mov         ecx,dword ptr [rbx+rax]              ; load one int from x into ecx
add         ecx,dword ptr [rax]                  ; add one int from y to the value in ecx and store the result in ecx
mov         dword ptr [rdx+rax],ecx              ; move the result out of ecx into the result array
lea         rax,[rax+4]                          ; increment the array indexer by one int (4 bytes)
sub         rdi,1                                ; decrement the loop counter
jne         main+160h                            ; if loop counter != 0 go back to SIMPLE_LOOP_START

Which lead to a conclusion that the compiler when operating C++ is able to auto-vectorize when necessary which gain a lot of execution time.
What can I do to bring the C#-called version closer to the performance of the native C++?
A thing to notice mainly is that vectorized will allways be faster than scalar. You will gain from 1.9 to 3.5 processing time using vectorized byte structure. You're using it in C++ (std::vector<uint8_t> image(width * height)) and not in C# (byte[] image = new byte[width * height];) which can have an effect. Vectorized is better for time saving because AVX2 instruction can operate on 8 or 16 bytes in one clock cycle and so parallelized. Where for the scalar container the processor executes one instruction per data element in sequence.
How does libraries like OpenCvSharp achieve excellent performance with P/Invoke?
OpenCV often avoids byte[] by using Mat objects that directly access the memory pointer that minimizes the marshaling needs.
Conclusion
I would highly recommend using vector instead of scalar container to save time. But keep note that you can use alternative "raw-er" memory storage, with memory pool and raw pointers, but to keep it simple & stupid (KISS) you can use Vectors. Notice that C++ will always be faster than C#, but you can get close.

You've clearly put a lot of effort into this, but I'm not sure that it actually answers the question. You talk a lot about C#'s SIMD, but OP isn't doing that at all. You talk about passing a memory pointer to minimise marshalling needs but OP is already doing that. You don't address why the P/Invoke is so slow at all.

OP is not doing any AVX code in .Net, so your answer does not apply
